# Stop user from entering characters beyond visible bounds of an edittext which has a multiline property?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to stop user from entering characters beyond visible bounds of a multiline-allowed EditText, dynamically? 
I like to show an alert when user reaches that limit. 
See, I cannot make use of the properties, android:maxLength and android:lines as such because the user is allowed to change the font size, face and style dynamically!
I guess we have to do the calculation in a TextWatcher

Comment: someone has -1ed without suggesting why; Is it a duplicate question? or what?

Comment: 1.I did not do the negative marking.2. TextWatcher is a good option.You can count the no. of characters entered. But how can you get the max no of characters possible in the visible bounds ?I hope your app supports multiple devices..

Comment: @Syamantak Basu how can you get the max no of characters possible in the visible bounds ?I hope your app supports multiple devices.. # Is that not possible  dynamically too? you see when we start typing the text beyond the visible rect, the scroll bar starts to appear, I just want that point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text font size is related to line height, you can use this to get the pixel height in your text for any font size, and prevent entering more data if condition is met.

code has not been checked but should work, will check properly if you have further issues.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
private String previousString="";
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      previousString=et.getText();
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if ((et.getLineCount()*et.getTextSize()) > et.getHeight) et.setText(previousString);
  }
});
```

also shout out to @nKn as if you noticed i copied the base of this from his answer.

Comment: &theellipsis Thanks....thats a good one, I will try.
 Is that not 
(et.getLineCount()*et.getTextSize()) < et.getHeight? correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: no, as it is in after text. it checks if the height of text is greater than height of text box, if it is then it will replace the new text with the old text. reverting it back to when the text height was smaller than the box height.

also please mark my answer as useful if you don't mind.

Comment: Just I wanted to make sure..before I mark it, right :p

Comment: I wasn't asking for you to mark it right, if you could click the up button to show it is useful that would be grate. tbh i need 50 rep to comment on another post to help with my work project.

Comment: its more than useful ..so I marked it right...btw I dont have enough rep to upvote :p

Comment: your code does exactly what I want to achieve, with only edit we have to check text length not equal to zero, as it falsely alerts "exceeding limit" for the first time... :p

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a static number of lines in your `EditText`, you can declare a `TextWatcher` and check the number of lines each times, so if it excedes the number of lines you declared, you'd remove the last character:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    if (et.getLineCount() > 3) {
      // Not tested, but it would be something like this
      et.setText(et.getText().toString().substring(0, et.getText().toString().getLength() - 1);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  }
});
```

Comment: If I know that "static number of lines in your EditText" I would end up using android:lines=3, right? 
but that is the problem, we dont know how much characters/lines the EditText(visible part of it) will be able to hold once user changes the font size or face...

Comment: I guess you cannot know the number of visible lines the user has, just the ones that are available.

Comment: also for this solution to work as intended you would need to place that line on the after text changed, otherwise the last character would be removed, and the new character would be added as normal. you would want to remove the new character.